# How to start another user session from CLI on SDDM?

Tags: command-line, 16.04, kubuntu, sddm

Currently the only way I know of is KDE lockscreen, but I also use openbox sometimes and while doing so have no way of starting a second user session.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's couple of ways of via command-line

1. `dm-tool switch-to-greeter`
2. `qdbus --system org.freedesktop.DisplayManager /org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Seat0 org.freedesktop.DisplayManager.Seat.SwitchToGreeter`
3. `qdbus org.gnome.ScreenSaver  /org/gnome/ScreenSaver org.gnome.ScreenSaver.Lock`

Any of these will lock your openbox session and switch you to login screen (except the last one, you have to press arrow to return to greeter as well) where you can  switch the user

Comment: Thank you, the second one worked. (First one requires `lightdm` and third one didn't work too in my case)

Comment: There's `lightdm-kde-greeter`  version of `lightdm` , consider giving that a go